# Стеганография LSB не корректное отображение русских символов

Tags: c#

Решил разобраться со стеганографией, очень заинтересовал эта тема, нашёл реализацию алгоритма на C# [собственно сама реализация](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/635715/Steganography-Simple-Implementation-in-Csharp)
начал разбираться, ввёл текст на английском и попробовал его скрыть в изображении, всё получилось и я смог извлечь этот текст из изображения. Я решил, что проблема в кодировке и решил загружать текст из файла подобной сточкой `text = File.ReadAllText(open_dialog.FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));`
но это не помогло. Собственно и решил обратится сюда.

Comment: пожалуйста, оформите свой вопрос согласно правилам StackOverflow: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error

Comment: и ещё вот, пригодится: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: поправил, нормально?

Comment: в вопрос принято включать код, с которым вы имеете дело, и который, по той или иной причине, вызвал у вас _конкретные_ вопросы. Указание ссылки на страницу не самая лучшая идея, так как страницу по ссылке могут завтра убрать, и ваш вопрос потеряет смысл и если у кого-то будет похожая проблема, то ваш вопрос уже ему мало поможет.

Comment: Вопрос был в том, что бы мне помогли найти что в этом коде мешает реализации моей задумки. Мне помогли. И думаю по ответу в низу в будущем, кого озаботит подобная проблема смогут разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема у кода в том, что он считает `char` восьмибитным.

Например, код

```
// check if new 8 bits has been processed
if (pixelElementIndex % 8 == 0)
```

при записи и

```
// if 8 bits has been added,
// then add the current character to the result text
if (colorUnitIndex % 8 == 0)
```

при чтении портят старшие биты.

---

Символы в .NET 16-битные вне зависимости от того, какую кодировку вы указываете при чтении. Кодировка играет роль лишь в определении того, какой символ прочитан из файла, а внутреннее представление всегда одно и то же.

Comment: ну, по сути это принцип этого алгоритма, он берёт 8 бит rgb и меняет  младшие биты получая новый пиксель

Comment: @Mio: Ну да, в этом и баг. В символе больше восьми бит. Автор кода не тестировал его на неанглийских текстах.

Comment: На счёт бага, как я понял в .NET  исправить его не получится и стоит искать другой алгоритм?

Comment: @Mio: потому что символы английского языка содержат нули в старшем байте, и поэтому потеря старшего байта не мешает. Баг исправить получится, просто нужно заменять не восемь бит, а все шестнадцать. Искать все места в коде, где автор предполагает восьмибитность `char` мне, простите, лень. Посмотрите сами, если хотите.

Comment: И что делать с этими 16 битами? По какому принципу заменять с 8 битами RGB ?

Comment: @Mio: А что такое «8 бит RGB»? RGB — это три числа по одному байту. Код распихивает символы побитно по байтам RGB, какая разница, распихивать 8 бит или 16?

Comment: ок, всё понял спасибо за ответ.